How to use static class functions inside a namespace?
I made a public static class so I can use its functions anywhere in my project. Such as:
public static class common {

    public static bool isEqual(float a, float b, float tolerance = 0.001f) {
        return Mathf.Abs(a - b) < tolerance;
    }

}

It works great most of the time, except for some Unity third party plugins. These plugins have namespace. Such as:
namespace Jason.RunDebug.Systems {

    public partial class RunDebugSystem : Singleton<RunDebugSystem> {

        public static void Init() {
            // ...
        }

    }

}

When I try to use my public static function inside this namespace, I get an error:

The name 'common' does not exist in the current context

Is there a way that I can use my static functions inside this namespace?

Did you add using common; at the top?

I tried that. I got error "The type or namespace name 'common' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Is that top file included in your project?

Sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean by top file? And how is it supposed to be included in the project? Thanks!

Your C# project file includes all the source files for the program you're compiling.  The source file that contains your class has to be in that list in order for the compiler to see it.

Ah, I see. I'm using Unity and it seems that all C# files in Assets folder are automatically included.

It is likely that plugin has an Assembly Definition. You can try to remove it, or create one for your code and reference it in the plugin's one. But best choice would be to not alter the code of the plugin and instead control it from your code (if possible, obviously).

You can put your common class inside its own namespace then any script using this class should have at the top using commonNamespace
